# CSS Layout, varient column widths

Tags: css, layout, grid, thumbnails

I want to produce a layout where thumbnails of a post flow through two different sized columns.

[image: Layout example]

I've looked at using css columns but as far as I can see they must be equal width.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks for your answer, it wasn't what I was looking for. I've used SUSY grids to achieve what I was after. You can set the grid function form 'float' to 'isolation' and that allows for ease of producing asymmetric grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SUSY grids allows you to easily create asymmetric grids (Like the example I posted in my original question). You can set the grid function form 'float' to 'isolation' and that allows you to easily produce asymmetric grids. [See this great intro article to SUSY grids.](http://css-tricks.com/build-web-layouts-easily-susy/)